# Returning a SQL query as one line of data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Apologies in advance, I have minimal experience in the SQL realm. One of our systems delivers data in a format that places individual lines items from a single record into separate rows. An example:

***Input***

```
Key   Desc   LineItem
55    AAA    1
55    BBB    2
66    CCC    1
```

I am looking to query this data in a way that would return the values for each **Key** as one line based on the line item number:

***Output***

```
Key   Desc1  Desc2
55    AAA    BBB
66    CCC    Null
```

Output.Desc1 = Input.Desc ***where*** Input.LineItem = 1
Output.Desc2 = Input.Desc ***where*** Input.LineItem = 2

Understanding how to return the desired output from my example should allow me to apply it to the larger data set. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Would you only ever have `LineItem` values in (1, 2)? This looks like a straightforward case for using `PIVOT`.

Comment: The Line Item Details could be as many as 30 I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @mathewb that `PIVOT` is an option for what you are looking for. I did work out an example for you. Using similar data that you put in your question.

Ref: [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testPivot;
CREATE DATABASE testPivot;
GO

USE [testPivot]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.input;
CREATE TABLE dbo.input 
    ([keyItem] int , 
     [description] varchar(255), 
     [lineItem] smallint);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

DECLARE @a int;
SELECT @a = 55;
WHILE (@a < 65)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @b int;
    SELECT @b = 1;
    WHILE (@b < 4)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO input VALUES (@a, CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), @b );
        SELECT @b = @b + 1;
    END
    SELECT @a = @a + 1;
END;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.input

SELECT [keyItem],
 [1] as [desc1], [2] as [desc2], [3] as [desc3]
FROM
 (SELECT 
    [keyItem],
    [lineitem],
    [description]
  FROM dbo.input) 
    AS sourcetable
PIVOT
    (MIN([description]) FOR lineitem IN ([1],[2],[3]))
  AS pivottable
```

Here is my result for input and output. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you @SqlWorldWide, your solution gave me a deeper understanding of the pivot function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mathewb for the PIVOT suggestion. Very specific to my data example, I was able to query the data with the following. @SqlWorldWide provided a much more elaborate solution to my question.

```
SELECT Key
 ,[1] AS Desc1
 ,[2] AS Desc2
FROM
 (SELECT ReqKey, Desc, LineItem
 FROM Input) p
PIVOT
(
 MAX (Desc)
 FOR LineItem IN ([1], [2])
) AS a
```